# When is a ethernet-to-thunderbolt cable necessary?

Tags: wifi, thunderbolt, ethernet

With the upgraded wireless on the latest 2013 MBP's when would I need this cable? I do have a Time Machine but the rate of data transfer wouldn't increase from having thunderbolt since the speed would only be as fast as its the slowest technology.

What else can I use it for?

Comment: One question per question, please. Just edit this down to one concrete "ask" and it will be reviewed for reopening.

Comment: Transferring 80GB of files from my MacBook Pro to my desktop machine. Would have taken the whole weekend with wifi.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for Apple to develop the Ethernet-to-thunderbolt cable is because the Macbook Pro retina line is too thin to fit the ethernet Port, thunderbolt is thin enough to fit. If you have a MacBook Pro retina you have 2 choses:

- Use Wifi
- Buy the Ethernet-to-thunderbolt cable to use cabled internet on you Macbook Pro retina

The only reason: People who don't have wifi, don't want to use it, don't have a fast rooter,...

If you have a normal unibody macbook pro there is no reason to buy the cable. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have WiFI wherever you go to with your MBP you probably won't need this cable. But there are places where the only network connectivity is available via Ethernet (hotels without WiFi for instance), also some people don't like running a WiFi at home to avoid the radiation.